# Android Multicast videostream

Tags: android, video-streaming, multicast

I'm developing a small demo player for Video Multicast Stream.

In the current state:

1. I have a working **UDP Multicast socket** (Android) and a **video Streamer** (PC).
2. I have a Video player (MediaPlayer/VideoView) that can open HTTP/RTSP Streams.
3. The Video is streamed in **MPEG 2 TS** - I can open the video using **HTTP Stream**.

The problem is that I can't open the UDP Stream with the player.

Here is the code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse("udp://239.192.1.31:1234");
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

Note:
I used tcpdump to make sure I was receiving the UDP Multicast stream.

Comment: how did you achieve UDP Multicast socket

Comment: Can you please post the code for the multicast socket?

Comment: Info on creating the socket can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342534/android-udp-multicast-with-ethernet

Answer (score 0):

The udp:// protocol is not supported in the android MediaPlayer, you have to use a library like Vitamio instead http://www.vitamio.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use exoplayer . It is an open source player managed by google only.
You can also extend by writing your own extractor and data source