# Multicast udp not working in android via ethernet cable

Tags: java, android, udp, ethernet, multicastsocket

I am trying to send a multicast udp(code to send multicast) from my ubuntu macine to my android app(code to receive multicast) via ethernet cable. I have dhcp server running in ubuntu machine and ethernet interface is also enabled in ubuntu machine.
I have also enabled ethernet tethering in my android device. I am able to perform normal tcp socket communication but multicast does not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Referred - [Android udp multicast with Ethernet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342534/android-udp-multicast-with-ethernet)